# Is it possible to pass value of <p> to <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<p>` that prints a value is it possible that the value can be printed in the `<input>`?

for example:

```
<p>2</p>

<input type="number">2</input>
```

Comment: Try looking at something like this https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/insert+value+in+input+field+javascript and rework it so it suits your need. Reminder is that you need to define id's in order to make it easier for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will require the use of Javascript. Add an `id` to your paragraph and input so you can identify them, then set the `value` of your input field to the `textContent` of your paragraph:

```js
let myParagraph = document.getElementById('my-paragraph');
let myInput = document.getElementById('my-input');

myInput.value = myParagraph.textContent;
```

```html
<p id="my-paragraph">2</p>

<input type="number" id="my-input"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

`Input` element has an attribute called `value`.
So you can do -

```js
<input type="number" value=2 />
```

Comment: No its not that, i want the input tag to get automatically the value of <p> tag

Comment: You can't do that in HTML. What you need to do is label the `<p>` in a way that will allow you to reference it, via a "class" or an "id". Then you can select the `<p>` and the `<input>` using code, i.e. - JavaScript, and place the value of the `<p>` inside the `<input>`. See if [this helps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-the-value-of-an-input-field-in-javascript/)

Comment: Do you have any reference i can look it up because i cant find it.